# Can I run a model trained using tensorflow on mxnet?

Tags: tensorflow, mxnet

I have models trained on tensorflow. Can I use mxnet in forward only mode to run these ?
https://github.com/dmlc/nnvm says this should be possible in future, but is the support available today ?

Comment: Almost all of mxnet developers are Chinese and so we're unlikely to get "eyes" on this SOF question. But I upvoted anyways.

Comment: This is more of a nnvm question, than a tensorflow/mxnet question.

Answer (score 1):

MXNet doesn't have tensorflow model converter yet. It does have a caffe-to-mxnet converter. So you can convert your tf model to caffe, that would work..

https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/master/tools/caffe_converter

Comment: How to convert tensorflow model to caffe? Thanks